# Was Paul ever recorded as having done a good deed?

Tags: sin, paul-apostle

The sting and polemic in Paul's letters is well documented. He fought with the authorities, the Apostles and there is an edge in every letter he wrote, even to those to people he claimed as "friends". He personally caused strife among early Christians and his writings are the prime weapons to continue his task up to the present. He was always boasting, but is there any recorded evidence of him following any one of the teachings or examples of Our Lord (apart from their shared celibacy)? Any one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks more like a statement in the form of a rhetorical question than an actual question seeking information.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). In particular, questions here must be objectively answerable rather than something seeking to air or solicit opinions. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Comment: Always be prepared to give to everyone the reason for the hope that you have. The question is answerable. Just thinking of all the ways that Paul served as a good example of Christian charity is inspiring.

Answer (score 3):

Jesus delivered his Great Commission to the Apostles and other disciples in Matthew 28:

> Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on
>   earth has been given to me. 19 Therefore go and make disciples of all
>   nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and
>   of the Holy Spirit, 20 and teaching them to obey everything I have
>   commanded you. And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the
>   age.”

Jesus said in John 14:

> Jesus replied, “Anyone who loves me will obey my teaching."

The Apostle Paul planted churches throughout Asia and Europe (as documented in Acts and the epistles), thus carrying out the Great Commission, obeying Jesus, and demonstrating his love for his Lord. Since God is good, to obey him is to do good.

In addition, Paul helped lead the first international relief mission in history, gathering funds from people throughout Europe to help the poor in the Middle East suffering a famine. (See Acts, and several of the epistles, including 2 Corinthians 8.)

Paul also wrote to a slave owner (Philemon) to persuade him not to punish his runaway slave (Onesimus), but instead accept him back as a brother and fellow Christian.

Paul cast a demon out of a woman. (Acts 16:18.)

Paul raised Eutychus from the dead. (Acts 20:7-12.)

Paul - after having instructed a church to discipline a member - later insisted they accept the man back and forgive him. (1 and 2 Corinthians.)

Paul explains to the soldier holding him captive how they may all be saved from drowning during a shipwreck, giving them all courage to survive. (Acts 27,28)

These are just the examples that come to mind off the top of my head.

As for all those arguments - the arguing is his best work of all. Without it I would not be saved. Without his disputes we wold not have the Gospel delivered once and for all to the saints. We would have another gospel - one that cannot save.